# Django - What field or fields in model should I be indexing to speed up the following query?

Tags: django, django-models

What field or fields in model should I be indexing to speed up the following query?

**Note this is an existing table with data, if that changes your answer**

Query `Subscriber.objects.filter(audience=audiencepk).order_by('-create_date')`

Models:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    audience = models.ForeignKey(Audience, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Audience(models.Model):
    audience_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
    store = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: If you're looping over this queryset and accessing Audience properties, you will do another query inside the loop. This is much more likely to be your performance problem and can be solved by adding [`.select_related('audience')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to the queryset.

Comment: @Melvyn very good recommendation, I think this may help my issue also

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It depends

Longer answer: It depends on the data itself, what other queries you need to be supporting, and how write-intensive your system is. Each index you add takes up space and will slow down writes, so it's impossible to just look at a data model and a single query and know what indices to add.

That said, if space and write performance are of no concern and we're only looking at this query. I *think* the answer is a multi-column index on audience and create_date (in that order).

```py
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    audience = models.ForeignKey(Audience, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['audience', '-create_date']),
        ]
```

Comment: What did you mean by test question, I'm not in school, do you mean I need to test it and see what works best? If not, that is rude.  Is audience field already being indexed as a foreign key?

Comment: create_date should be descending

Comment: @iklinac good catch. I'm used to it not making a difference in some databases.

Comment: @Padoga I just meant that the way the question was phrased reminded me a lot of some take-home interview questions i've seen. It wasn't intended to be rude, i've removed that remark.

I believe Django will automatically create an index for foreign keys, which you might want to disable if you're creating this additional index.

Comment: Don't disable index on Foreign keys (not even sure you can), cause it will mess up joins. It's perfectly fine to have multiple indexes involving the same column. The planner will select the one that it thinks is most appropriate. EXPLAIN should show the selected index.

Comment: @Melvyn I think you agree with answer Andrew has provided? You are just saying no need to disable foreign keys. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. But I would look at [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-explain.html) to verify it's being used for the query. If not, I'd just put an index on create_date. Here's some [food for thought](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/combined-indexes-vs-separate-indexes-in-postgresql/).